# Abbreviate the site name to an acronym in space-sensitive UI components

Tags: feature-request, design, site-name

"Programming Language Design and Implementation" is a very long name. It might actually have the longest name of any SE site, although I can't be bothered to check. This leads to situations like [Weird padding on the VTC privilege notice](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/weird-padding-on-the-vtc-privledge-notice), where the extreme width of the name causes weird UI issues like buttons being squished. I propose that in situations like that, our name should be abbreviated to just "PLDI", which is much shorter.

Comment: Or “programming language design”, in the same manner as code golf is

Comment: I just checked, the longest open site name is "Software Quality Assurance & Testing" (36 characters), while "Programming Language Design and Implementation" is 46 characters -- so this is the new longest name.

Comment: I like "langdev" as an abbreviation. It has the benefit of being pronounceable.

Comment: Also, the leftmost links on the footer look weird when you take a look at the title; in other sites, the name is short enough that you feel it's normal, but here our long name makes the links look extremely to the left in contrast with out title.